# WSO2 - 500]: Internal server error Error while adding new API null--1.0.0 - Error while performing registry transaction operation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Community,
Need your kind advise and if anyone has encountered this issue.  I'm trying to create a API in WSO2 API Manager version 3.0.0.

However, when create I get below error.

**Error/Problem:**

> 500]: Internal server error Error while adding new API :
>   null-CustomerInfo-1.0.0 - Error while performing registry transaction
>   operation

**Logs:**

```
2020-02-08T18:55:40,331 [-] [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-10] ERROR ApisApiServiceImpl Error while adding new API : null-CustomerInfo-1.0.0 - Error while performing registry transaction operation
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException_aroundBody124(AbstractAPIManager.java:1832) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:1830) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI_aroundBody142(APIProviderImpl.java:3335) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:3247) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI_aroundBody46(APIProviderImpl.java:772) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:767) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI_aroundBody0(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:64) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:278) [classes/:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:835) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: seems the provider name is sent as null, can you please elaborate how you made the API create request ? Is it through the publisher UI or by directly calling the REST API ? If you called the REST API directly then can you attach the payload request you sent ?